# Is it possible to do http://www.something.domainname.com where something could be a variable?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like for any user come to redirect to their page on my site after they login with **.htaccess**.

For example, "username" login and redirects to:

```
http://www.username.domainname.com
```

That will be handled internally like this:

http://www.domainname.com/users.php?user=username

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is by doing a [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

If you are writing in PHP, you can do this:

```
<?php 
$username = $_GET["user"]; // Note that this is user input (which could be malicious)
header("Location: http://www.{$username}.domainname.com/"); 
?>
```

But, as you have not specified a language, that is just one example.  You can easily search for how to do a redirect in whatever framework you are using and there should be good examples.

---

If you want to go the other way, try a [URL Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/).

Here's a very basic one that should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.domainname\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$         http://www.domainname.com/users.php?user=%1 [L,R]
```

The rule looks for any request that matches www.*(something other than .)*.domainname.com and sends back a redirect request for http://www.domainname.com/users.php?user=*(something other than .)*

Comment: not like that user wiil enter like http://www.username.domainname.com/

and then he redirect to http://www.domainname.com/users.php?user=username url will stay same in browser i want to handle it bu htaccess

Comment: Oh, you want to go the other way.  It was a little unclear from your question.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding